# How to pass current object to function?

Tags: php, class, object, methods, this

```
$hookObj = t3lib_div::getUserObj($classRef);

if (method_exists($hookObj, $func)) {
    $hookObj->$func($params, $this);
}
```

I saw above script pass `$this` to a function, so I am trying to figure out how to pass `$this` to a function, I did below test:

```
class a
{

    public $var1 = 'var1';
    public $var2 = 'var2';

}

$obj0 = new a;

class b
{

    function init($pObj)
    {
        var_dump($pObj->var1);
    }

}

$obj1 = new b;
$obj1->init($obj0);
```

I can pass an object  `$obj0` to function, but how could I pass `$this` the current object to function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$this` is a reference to the current instance object of a class. if your active scope is within a class where `$this` is available you can pass it to another class function. as follows

```
class .... { 
    public function passRef() {
       $foo = new Bar();
       $foo->fooBar($this);
    }
}
```